# Elisp: is symbol-name an O(1) operation wrt name length?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have to call it a bunch of times, so I'm wondering
if I should do some optimization, like an alist of symbol and name.

I've glanced at the C source code and it seems that it's just a pointer operation,
but I may have misunderstood and I'd like to know for sure.

Comment: `symbol-name` returns the name of the symbol as a string. What kind of dependency on the length of the name do you expect? Besides possible copies of the value.

Comment: Copy of the value is an O(N) operation w.r.t. name length.

Comment: So, you have your answer? But you cannot really rely on a copy happening because it can be elided.

Comment: That's the thing I'm not sure about. Is the copy being made, or I'm just getting a reference?

Comment: Ah, I understand. A string is an array. Arrays are referential. Easy code to check this: `(setq myval "foobar")
(defun get-myval()
  myval)
(aset (get-myval) 0 ?b)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`symbol-name` does not copy, so it's an O(1) operation, yes.  It can be a source of problem, if you do `(aset (symbol-name 'car) 1 ?d)`.